# Multi column hierarchical query in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-query, connect-by

I have a assignment table containing employees with employee id and project id, with primary key as assignment id. A project can have multiple employees, and an employee can be in multiple projects. Given an employee id, it's required to get a resultset containing assignment ids of all the projects related to the employee, and all the employees of those projects in a recursive manner. How can this be achieved in sql(preferred) or plsql? I am using Oracle SQL.

Table

| assignment_id | employee_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 1001 | 2001 | 3000 |
| 1002 | 2000 | 3001 |
| 1003 | 2002 | 3001 |
| 1004 | 2002 | 3002 |
| 1005 | 2003 | 3002 |
| 1007 | 2004 | 3002 |
| 1008 | 2005 | 3002 |
| 1009 | 2009 | 3004 |

Eg: Given 2000, the below resultset would be returned

| assignment_id | employee_id | project_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 1001 | 2001 | 3000 |
| 1002 | 2000 | 3001 |
| 1003 | 2002 | 3001 |
| 1004 | 2002 | 3002 |
| 1005 | 2003 | 3002 |
| 1007 | 2004 | 3002 |
| 1008 | 2005 | 3002 |

Below query is running into cycles causing huge resultsets for complex hierarchies. Similar issues using connect by.

```
with all_subs(assignment_id, employee_id, project_id) as 
(
    select assignment_id, employee_id, project_id
    from csm_assignments
    and employee_id = 70001
    union all
    select s.assignment_id, s.employee_id, s.project_id
    from csm_assignments s, all_subs s1
    and (
        (s.employee_id = s1.employee_id and s.project_id != s1.project_id) OR
        (s.employee_id != s1.employee_id and s.project_id = s1.project_id)
    )
) cycle assignment_id set is_loop to 'Y' default 'N'
select * 
from csm_assignments
where assignment_id in (select assignment_id from all_subs);
```

Comment: did up read up about CONNECT BY?  You need to show some effort here.

Comment: a simple recursive CTE should work just fine

Comment: Using connect by, or recursive CTE is going into cycles in some use cases resulting a huge resultset or a timeout, for the clause where we need to get all the employees for a project. prior employee_id = employee_id and prior project_id != project_id is working fine to get all projects for an employee, but the other way round is running into loops

Comment: Please provide create table statements, sample data and expected results

Answer (score 0):

assignment ids of all the projects related to the employee:

```
WITH emp_proj as (
    SELECT project_id
    FROM csm_assignments
    WHERE employee_id = 70001
)
SELECT ca.assignment_id
FROM csm_assignments ca
INNER JOIN emp_proj ep on ca.project_id = ep.project_id
```

all the employees of those projects:

```
WITH emp_proj as (
    SELECT project_id
    FROM csm_assignments
    WHERE employee_id = 70001
)
SELECT DISTINCT ca.employee_id
FROM csm_assignments ca
INNER JOIN emp_proj ep on ca.project_id = ep.project_id
```

Comment: I don't think this will give the entire resultset. Assignments 1004-1008 won't be returned.